# Accessing Spring application context from Jetty WebAppContext

Tags: spring-mvc, jetty, embedded-jetty

I initialize Jetty WebAppContext with the web application data. I am using embedded jetty to start the web application. How can i get access to the application context of the web application. I need to pass some data to application context of the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your issue resolved but may be someone face same issue and I myself had to struggle lot for answer. So [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070022/how-to-make-embedded-jetty-use-the-appcontext-its-defined-in-as-parent-context) is my answer where I mentioned how I resolved problem of registering beans loaded in application context to web context so that it can be used by Jetty instead of creating new instance.